# Socket.io does not emit anything when a message is sent

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

The expected result is that after the user presses "enter" key or the send button that the message should display in the chat box. However, nothing occurs upon these two events and no chat is saved in the database.

In the chrome console, I am getting the following errors:

```
chat.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at n.<anonymous> (chat.js:7)
    at n.emit (socket.io.slim.js:6)
    at n.emit (socket.io.slim.js:8)
    at n.onconnect (socket.io.slim.js:8)
    at n.onpacket (socket.io.slim.js:8)
    at n.<anonymous> (socket.io.slim.js:8)
    at n.emit (socket.io.slim.js:6)
    at n.ondecoded (socket.io.slim.js:6)
    at a.<anonymous> (socket.io.slim.js:8)
    at a.n.emit (socket.io.slim.js:6)
```

Everything else should be working fine, as when I manually add chats to the database, they appear in the chatbox.

Here is the javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // allow "Enter" key to send message
        document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener("keydown", event => {
            if (event.key == "Enter") {
                document.getElementById('#button-send').click();
            }
        })

        document.querySelector("#button-send").addEventListener("click", () => {

            let timestamp = new Date;
            timestamp = timestamp.toLocaleTimeString();

            // Save user input
            let msg = document.getElementById("text").value;

            socket.emit('send message', msg, timestamp)

            document.getElementById("text").value = '';
        });
    });

    socket.on('announce message', data => {

        // Format message
        if (data.friend_id === data.user_id) {
            let row1 = data.msg
            let row2 = data.timestamp
            document.querySelector('#newmsg').value += row 
            document.querySelector('#newdate').value += row 
        }
        else {
            let row1 = data.msg
            let row2 = data.timestamp
            document.querySelector('#newchat').value += row 
            document.querySelector('#newchat').value += row 
        }      
    })
})
```

Here is the app.py:

```
@socketio.on("send message")
def send_msg(msg, timestamp):
    chat = session.get['friend']

    friend_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username", {"username":chat}).fetchone()[0]

    convo_id = db.execute("SELECT chat_id FROM chat_ids WHERE p1_id =: p1_id, p2_id =: p2_id", {"p1_id":session["user_id"], "p2_id":friend_id})

    db.execute("INSERT INTO messages (conversation_id, sender, reciever, time, message) VALUES (:id, :sender, :reciever, :time, :message)", 
        {"coversation_id": convo_id, "sender":session["user_id"], "reciever": friend_id, "time":timestamp, "message":msg})

    emit('announce message', {
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'msg': msg,
        'user_id':session["user_id"],
        'friend_id': friend_id},
        chat = chat)
```

Here is the relevant html file

```
<body>
        <div class="messaging">
          <div class="inbox_msg">
              <div class="mesgs">
                <div class="msg_history">
                  {% for message in messages %}
                    {% if message["sender"] == session.user_id %}
                      <div class="outgoing_msg">
                        <div class="sent_msg">
                          <p id="newmsg">{{message[3]}}</p>
                          <span class="time_date" id="newdate">{{message[2]}}</span>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="incoming_msg">
                          <div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="">
                            <div class="received_withd_msg">
                              <p id="newmsg">{{message[3]}}</p>
                              <span class="time_date" id="newdate">{{message[2]}}</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="type_msg">
                  <div class="input_msg_write">
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="write_msg" placeholder="Type a message" />
                    <button id="button-send" class="msg_send_btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` means that you're trying to attach an event listener to an object variable that has nothing in it.

Comment: So one of your query selectors is probably failing.  Check to make sure that each query selector is actually returning the object you specified in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> chat.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

as it states; the event is being attached to an object that is of type null. It occurs on the following line

```
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener("keydown", event => {
```

Make sure that the `id` called `text` is valid and you should also consider making `id` name bit more unique. Moreover, this can also happen if your `Js` file is in the `head` section of your `HTML` file and the reference you make with `#text` is defined in the `body` section. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192080/6505847) for a better explanation.