# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (multiple forms)

Tags: javascript, forms, giphy

Hello fellow developers,

I have a simple question. I'm working on my javascript skills, which are obviously not the best :). I'm trying to code a search box with the giphy API, by [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfV7LSxITtI&list=PLoN_ejT35AEifvd_YFvPTO3fvbD9YwcSg&index=6). My code was working to 100% like the code displayed in the tutorial until video 5, but now (video 6) it's not working anymore.

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". I [googled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191982/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null/57192080) a lot and tried the [fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null/30063375) which I found here, but they are not working on my code :/ The funny part of this is, that my code is working on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mauricewoitzyk-ger/pen/zYqazWM)! So the only difference between codepen and my local website, are multiple search forms and bootstrap. So I'm guessing the problem are multiple search forms, because of this lines:

```
const searchGif = document.getElementById("search-gif");
const searchInput = document.getElementById("gif-search-string"); 
searchGif.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   const query = searchInput.value;
   search(query);
})
```

But I thought because I'm grabbing the right form by ID before I execute the rest of my javascript code, it is ok? So I hope that you can help me to resolve my problem. Like I said, I'm not very good in JS and just trying to get better and better <3.

PS: loading my script by script tag at the end of the html body
PS2: Here is my complete HTML Code -> [index.php](https://codepen.io/mauricewoitzyk-ger/pen/abNKKzB) - [timeline-gif.php](https://codepen.io/mauricewoitzyk-ger/pen/poyKKJz)

Comment: How do you load your js into the page? Script tag? Please add your html head to the question.

Comment: <script src="js/get-gif.js"></script> @ the end of my body tag

Comment: I am quite sure that your `searchGif` is assigned before the element itself is created/rendered.
To wait for this to happen see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/5243272
Codepen wraps the user's code automatically which probably is the reason that it works there.

Comment: But this is exactly the same way i'am doing right now?  First: LOAD HTML THEN JS? I dont see the difference :(

Answer (score 0):

It's how you "start" your code. Loaded !== rendered (not 100% sure that these are the correct terms).
Try to wrap it in a self executing function:

```
(function() {
 // Put your code here - dom should be available
})();
```

Comment: I was trying this already because its a solution in the posts which are linked in the main topic on top. But its not working :( I'll get 2 errors then not just one.

Comment: the same error, but no on 2 different lines. ( first like the example on top and the second error on the line where I close the function (end of the script)

Comment: Then I think you'll have to post your whole html. Hard to reproduce otherwise.

Comment: [index.php](https://codepen.io/mauricewoitzyk-ger/pen/abNKKzB) - [timeline-gif.php](https://codepen.io/mauricewoitzyk-ger/pen/poyKKJz)